# How would I got about testing db connection settings in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a ini file with db connection settings. I am creating an installer and need help to:

1. test db connection settings in ini file with errors (wrong user/pass or cannot select db)
2. insert db structure using .sql file.

Is this possible with ZF, I can't find any info anywhere. Should I just do this using direct queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Saying "I WILL BE OFFERING BOUNTY" is another way of saying "I don't want an answer for 2 days until I add the bounty". Just ask your question, and if you don't get a good answer *then* you can add a bounty

Comment: What a surprise, nothing about the answer to the question. I wonder if any questions actually get answered on this site? Beginner friendly?LOL I don't think so.

Comment: Anyway, I see your point, I've edited the question. Just trying to get some answers because I usually have to wait 2 days for an answer here unless it's something simple like what is 1+1? In which case it will be closed for not being specific enough HAHAHA this site is going to drive me insane!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your unit test, you could probably call `$adapter->getConnect()` within a `try/catch` that checks for a `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception`, subclasses of which are thrown on a failed connection. In the `catch`, you can call `$this->fail()` to signal the failed test.

But typically, you would have a different set of db connection params when `APPLICATION_ENV = 'testing'` than you would for the other `APPLICATION_ENV`'s. So in this sense, I am with @jakenoble. It sounds less like a unit testing issue than a deployment issue. As such, some kind of command-line script - even one that uses the same bootstrap as the main app - might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Add `$db->getConnection()` to make connections and catch the error if any comes around.

```
try {  
    $db->getConnection();
} catch( Exception $e ) { 
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    die;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642275/zend-framework-2-base-path-access-in-controller

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ZF specific so isn't something you should be accomplishing with ZF. ZF doesn't have a Database Adapter called `MightExist`. If the username or password are wrong then ZF will error and you get no where.

Firstly is this a deployment issue or a testing issue?

If it is a deployment issue then you need something to deploy your code automatically, maybe a bash script? This could check the users in the database without relying on ZF at all. The bash script could also set up your database by importing your .sql file.

If it is a testing issue then it is different all together. You should use something like [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) to test for the existence of users, their passwords and to check that data exists, if not insert it using your .sql file.