# zend framework 2 base path access in controller

Tags: zend-framework2

How can i call basePath helper in controller in ZF 2. I have to redirect to a particular url in which i need base path. 
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($basePath.'/application/rent/search');

Comment: In my tests this is not necessary. Simply use `$this->redirect()->toUrl('/application/rent/search')`

Answer (score 7):

Here's an [easy method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644702/94289) to make all view helpers available from within the controllers. So you should be able to use the following:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $renderer = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');
    $url = $renderer->basePath('/application/rent/search');
    $redirect = $this->plugin('redirect');
    return $redirect->toUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: Note that the redirect controller plugin also has a toRoute() method which makes the use of the base path obsolete.

Comment: The best solution that i see. Its is very clean if you use factories in controller config.

Answer (score 3):

The full base url (http://...) can be determined from within the controller as follows:

```
$event = $this->getEvent();
$request = $event->getRequest();
$router = $event->getRouter();
$uri = $router->getRequestUri();
$baseUrl = sprintf('%s://%s%s', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getHost(), $request->getBaseUrl());
```

Comment: there is difference in baseUrl and basePath

Answer (score 1):

try

```
class XxxController extends AbstractActionController
{

...

public function basePath()
{
    $basePath = $this->serviceLocator
        ->get('viewhelpermanager')
        ->get('basePath');
    return $basePath();
}
```

in

OR

```
public function algoAction()
{
    echo $this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
}
```

http://project.com/profile

returns ""

http://localhost/~limonazzo/public/profile

returns /~limonazzo/public/